# Usage of subcaption leads to a misalignment (horizontal and vertical)

Tags: positioning, subcaption

I use  the package "subcaption" to put my pictures into my script. I prefere to use subcaption instead of subfig because if I use  \continuedFloat it makes a correct enumeration.

Sadly the last two pictures are always slightly horizontally miscentered. Sometimes even the vertical distance of the last two pictures is completely wrong as you can see in the example.

This is the code I use for my pictures:

```
 \documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering
\subcaptionbox{Abstand\label{bla}}
{\includegraphics[width=0.451\textwidth]{bla}}
\qquad
\subcaptionbox{Abstand\label{bla}}
{\includegraphics[width=0.451\textwidth]{bla}}
\qquad
\subcaptionbox{Abstand\label{bla}}
{\includegraphics[width=0.451\textwidth]{bla}}
\qquad
\subcaptionbox{Abstand\label{bla}}
{\includegraphics[width=0.451\textwidth]{bla}}
\qquad
\subcaptionbox{Abstand\label{bla}}
{\includegraphics[width=0.451\textwidth]{bla}}
\qquad
\subcaptionbox{Abstand\label{bla}}
{\includegraphics[width=0.451\textwidth]{bla}}
\qquad
\subcaptionbox{Abstand\label{bla}}
{\includegraphics[width=0.451\textwidth]{bla}}
\qquad
\subcaptionbox{Abstand\label{bla}}
{\includegraphics[width=0.451\textwidth]{bla}}
\vspace{3mm}
\caption{hallo}\label{bla}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

And it gives me this wrong result:
[image: Misalignment]
<sub>(source: [bilderload.com](http://www.bilderload.com/daten/abstaende1O42E.gif))</sub>

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

I use texlive 2014.

Thank you very much :-)

Comment: Is this the exact output by your minimal working example? Since there are no 8 figures in your example, i seriously doubt it.

Comment: Add a blank line before the `vspace` or use `\par`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the reason is the length of the subcaption.

In all 8 captions I have used the same caption togehter with a number.
This number was from a) to d) two digits long and for the next four pictures just one digit.

This one more digit does not make a linebreak in the caption! 
Or better there ist no visible break but it seems like there is a critical length of a subcaption not breaking up the caption itself but making an empty break.

So I think the solution is to make the longer caption shorter or to use a invisible "~" at the end of the shorter captions.

For centering the last two pictures the "\par" before the vspace Johannes suggested helps.

Thank you very much :-)